# What is loot specialization in WoW?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Currently I'm trying to create a healing build. By mere chance I saw, when I right-clicked my character unitframe, that I could select a "loot specialization".

What is that? Does that mean that the loot I get will be for the healing class? Does it mean I don't get items for other specs?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will prioritize the type of gear you want to see when looting bosses and mobs.

> Loot Specialization is a feature introduced in Patch 5.3 which allows
>   players to set the loot priority for their character to favor a
>   particular specialization. This loot priority setting only affects
>   bonus rolls, Raid Finder loot, World Bosses loot and Heroic Scenario
>   loot. This feature was primarily added to allow players to collect
>   off-spec gear.

https://wowwiki.fandom.com/wiki/Loot_Specialization

Comment: IIRC the possibility to "change" mainspec in raid finder was already existing in Cataclysm. So you could tank while rolling for DPS gear